# Как внутри шорткода WP вывести функцию php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, acf, shortcode

Извините за глупый вопрос.

Вывожу товар при помощи шорткода `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[product id="9514"]' ); ?>`

Мне необходимо вместо значения id (в данном случае "9514") вывести значение функции the_field('wine_box_№1')

Данная конструкция не работает:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[product id='".the_field('wine_box_№1')."']"); ?>
```

И так тоже не работает:

```
<?php
$id= the_field('wine_box_№1');
echo do_shortcode("[product id='$id']");
?>
```

Вы уж извините, что я, такой дурак, к Вам сюда пришел. Ткните меня носом, где я не прав.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш пример должен работать. Но лучше использовать "классический способ склеивания".

```
<?php
$id = the_field('wine_box_№1');
echo do_shortcode("[product id='".$id."']");
?>
```

Если результат работы шорткода не устраивает Вас. Выведите отдельно ид и строку целиком:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($id);
echo '<br/>';
echo "[product id='".$id."']";
echo '</pre>
```

ЗЫ. Меня смущает знак "№" в `the_field('wine_box_№1')`. Вы уверены, что slug ACF такое поддерживает?

Comment: Знак "№" убрал, но результат не изменился. На выходе я получаю значение the_field('wine_box_1') текстом, до конструкции, которую выводит функция echo do_shortcode("[product id='$id']");

Comment: @ВикторУспенский, `echo "[product id='".$id."']";` - можете скинуть, что выводит на экран

Comment: @ВикторУспенский, попробуйте так `echo do_shortcode("[product id='".trim($id)."']");` или `echo do_shortcode("[product id='".(int)$id."']");`

Comment: @ Node_pro, результат тот же. Значение `$id` выводится до конструкции, которую выводит `do_shortcode("[product id='']");`

Comment: @ Node_pro, спасибо Вам огромное за внимание к моему вопросу и консультацию. Проблема была решена с помощью использования `get_field()`, а не  `the_field()`.

Comment: @ВикторУспенский, не заметил. Рад, что у Вас вышло. Удачи!